# How do I enter " character in console commands?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm 78 and not very computer savvy, I have a problem with entering console commands.

I want "fire arrows" but don't know how to enter " " those 2 comma's in air?
I have a key for that but every time I press it a square shows up!
Can someone please help me?